# -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x14539180 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, core-data

I recently jumped to use Xcode7.3.1 and convert my code, but I'm facing some kind of problem here,this is how I used to use it in Swift1.1 but I am getting error

> -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x14539180

Here is my Code :

```
func deleteData(modelName:String, predicate:String!) -> Bool {

  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  let cdhObj = appDelegate.cdh
  let fReq: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: modelName)
  print("\(fReq)")
  print("\(predicate)")

  //Check whether predicate is there
  if (predicate != nil) {
     fReq.predicate = NSPredicate(format:predicate)
     print("fReq.predicate-------\(fReq.predicate)")
  }

  print("Reached Here_1")
  print("Reached Here\(fReq.predicate!)")
  var result = try! cdhObj.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fReq) //getting error in this line  
  print("Reached Here_2")

  for resultItem in result {
     let countryItem: AnyObject = resultItem

     cdhObj.managedObjectContext!.deleteObject(countryItem as! NSManagedObject)
  }
  cdhObj.saveContext(cdhObj.managedObjectContext!)

  result = try! cdhObj.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fReq)
  if result.isEmpty {
     return true
  } else {
     return false
  }

 }
```

Any help will be Appreciated!!

Comment: Could you provide a *predicate* string that you passed to your func?

Comment: String is :- (sno == min:(sno) AND isOnline == 1)

Comment: I think your fetchRequest by your predicate string returned NSNumber, not a NSArray, try to modify this string or send nil

Comment: Can you please provide example string?

Comment: try the first send nil value as predicate string. Will it return a list or crash again?!

Comment: crashed again! <NSFetchRequest: 0x1a091d80> (entity: RecentLocationSearched; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ) this gives me when i given predicate a nil

Comment: if you sent predicate as a nil value you no need set fReq.predicate, remove it

Comment: well that worked like a charm Thanks !!

Comment: So the problem in your predicate string, modify it to right format

Answer (score 0):

Just click [+] in the bottom left corner of the Breakpoint Navigator to add a breakpoint and try setting a symbolic breakpoint with:

> -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]

[image]

Comment: It's simple to create a global Exception handler. There is even a special button for it.

Comment: where is that button? from where I can do that? thank @Sulthan for your comemnt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode